# Does not detach database by sp_detach_db in pyodbc

Tags: python, t-sql, pyodbc

I am trying to detach the database, but for some reason it does not detach with no error, am I missing something?

```py
import pyodbc
params = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\RISKSPEC_PSA2012;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;Pwd=sa_pasw;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
try:
    with pyodbc.connect(params) as cnxn:
        with cnxn.cursor() as cursor:
            cnxn.autocommit = True
            cursor.execute(
                '''
                USE [master];
                ALTER DATABASE [sss] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
                EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname=sss;
                ''')
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    QMessageBox.warning(self, 'pyodbc', ex.args[0])
```

**SQLServer 2012** version: *11.0.2100*

**pyodbc** version: *4.0.31*

Comment: Testing suggests that despite the `SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT` your code will fail if there are any active connections to the database. You may need to forcibly drop those connections before trying to detach the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for Gord Thompson for the tip.

Fixes:

- SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT -> [SET TRUSTWORTHY ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Remove from connect params "Trusted_Connection=yes;", It associates the system user instead of "sa" user.

```py
import pyodbc
params = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\RISKSPEC_PSA2012;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;Pwd=sa_pasw;'
    try:
        with pyodbc.connect(params) as cnxn:
            cnxn.autocommit = True
            with cnxn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    '''
                    USE [master];
                    ALTER DATABASE [sss] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
                    EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname=sss;
                    ''')
    except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'pyodbc', ex.args[0])
```